How do I request permission to read phone's storage? - Kotlin Android
I'm new to Android software development, on Kotlin, there was a problem that the application basically refuses to request permission to read memory, in particular audio files, even if you manually give this permission (in the application settings on the device itself, an item appears to read these very audio files, but when you first launch no standard access windows not output)
Тhat is, even if permission to read this type of file is not required in Android api 13, the application still does not display audio files in the list.
**My Manifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
            android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MPMP"
            tools:targetApi="31">


        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

**Theme.AppCompat - yes, it may not be used much anymore, but for my application personally, this part is a brick in its operability (lol)
please be understanding
Also, you can tell me how to "search" all audio files on the device (regardless of the folder)?
this is the only and latest version of the manifest code in which at least a request for permission to read audio files appears in the application settings.

RTFM READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE has no effect since Android 13 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

private fun requestPermission() {
        val permissions: Array<String> = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            )
        } else {
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
                Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO,
                Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            )
        }

        Permissions.check(context, permissions, null, null, object : PermissionHandler() {
            override fun onGranted() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

                    if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                        try {
                            val intent =
                                Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
                            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
                            intent.data = Uri.parse(
                                String.format(
                                    "package:%s", context?.packageName
                                )
                            )
                            startActivity(intent)
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            val intent = Intent()
                            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onDenied(
                context: Context?, deniedPermissions: ArrayList<String>?
            ) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    context, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        })

    }

private fun checkPermission(): Boolean {
        context?.let {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                val storagePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    it, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                )
                val contactPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    it, Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                )
                return storagePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && contactPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            } else {
                val readImages = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    it, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
                )
                val readAudio = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    it, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO
                )
                val readVideo = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    it, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
                )
                val contactPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    it, Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                )
                return readImages == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && readVideo == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && readAudio == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && contactPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            }
        } ?: return false

    }

add this in build.gradle
    implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'

then add this in manifest file
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />

where you want to check permission call checkpermission(),if not not allowed then call requestPermission method.
this will work on all android versions

To get all music files on the device.

 val selection = StringBuilder("is_music != 0 AND title != ''")

        // Display audios in alphabetical order based on their display name.
        val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME} ASC"
        val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
            EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            selection.toString(),
            null,
            sortOrder
        )

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                val id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID))
                val title: String =
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))
                val duration: Int =
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION))
                val size = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE))
                val artist =
                  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST))
             } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        cursor?.close()

